# How do I debug a memory leak in a Firefox / Vue SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory

I have a rather large single page application written in Vue. For a long time now, I have the problem that refreshing the page many times (like you do while debugging code) the memory footprint of Firefox grows to the point where the application is becoming extremely slow. By that point I need to exit the browser or tab and start over. The problem seems to get worse while the application has been growing.

Note that this only happens when refreshing the browser, so it seems unlikely that there is a problem with my SPA keeping event handlers running etc. It does not happen in Chrome.

How can I find out what the source of this problem is?

Here is a dump of the about:memory page, after about 25 refreshes. This fragment is about the Web process, but the main process also grows in size. As you can see the footprint is about 1.5gb. On a first load the footprint is about 200 Mb:

```
1,555,808,240 B (100.0%) -- explicit
├──1,163,196,640 B (74.76%) -- window-objects
│  ├────988,369,312 B (63.53%) -- top(http://localhost:8080/edit, id=23)
│  │    ├──662,598,704 B (42.59%) -- active
│  │    │  ├──655,177,728 B (42.11%) -- window(http://localhost:8080/edit)
│  │    │  │  ├──413,153,488 B (26.56%) -- js-realm(http://localhost:8080/edit)
│  │    │  │  │  ├──324,578,992 B (20.86%) ++ classes
│  │    │  │  │  ├───84,657,040 B (05.44%) ++ scripts
│  │    │  │  │  ├────2,541,504 B (00.16%) ── realm-tables [31]
│  │    │  │  │  ├────1,277,952 B (00.08%) ── saved-stacks-set [31]
│  │    │  │  │  └───────98,000 B (00.01%) ── sundries/malloc-heap [31]
│  │    │  │  ├──193,810,592 B (12.46%) -- layout
│  │    │  │  │  ├──189,408,512 B (12.17%) ── style-sheets [31]
│  │    │  │  │  ├────3,653,904 B (00.23%) ++ style-sets
│  │    │  │  │  ├──────265,792 B (00.02%) ++ style-structs
│  │    │  │  │  ├──────166,080 B (00.01%) ── svg-mapped-declarations [31]
│  │    │  │  │  ├──────115,128 B (00.01%) ++ display-list-arena
│  │    │  │  │  ├───────59,448 B (00.00%) ++ pres-arena
│  │    │  │  │  ├───────54,960 B (00.00%) ++ computed-values
│  │    │  │  │  ├───────46,216 B (00.00%) ── display-list
│  │    │  │  │  ├───────15,544 B (00.00%) ── pres-shell
│  │    │  │  │  ├───────12,576 B (00.00%) ── frame-properties
│  │    │  │  │  ├────────5,872 B (00.00%) ── text-runs
│  │    │  │  │  ├────────5,536 B (00.00%) ── element-data-objects
│  │    │  │  │  └────────1,024 B (00.00%) ── pres-contexts
│  │    │  │  ├───48,136,288 B (03.09%) ++ dom
│  │    │  │  └───────77,360 B (00.00%) ── property-tables [31]
│  │    │  └────7,420,976 B (00.48%) ++ window(https://www.youtube.com/embed/wBlZCrV_J-U)
│  │    ├───10,953,656 B (00.70%) ++ js-zone(0x16444d000)
│  │    ├───10,874,648 B (00.70%) ++ js-zone(0x1963ab000)
│  │    ├───10,872,360 B (00.70%) ++ js-zone(0x17214e000)
│  │    ├───10,804,680 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x189c34000)
│  │    ├───10,748,856 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x18e8a8000)
│  │    ├───10,700,456 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x163e27000)
│  │    ├───10,696,184 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x1777e6000)
│  │    ├───10,696,024 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x165cdb000)
│  │    ├───10,664,408 B (00.69%) ++ js-zone(0x18a7c4000)
│  │    ├───10,646,808 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x187bcd000)
│  │    ├───10,635,640 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x17f490000)
│  │    ├───10,626,840 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x1660b6000)
│  │    ├───10,615,464 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x16e363000)
│  │    ├───10,614,584 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x16dcfe000)
│  │    ├───10,614,392 B (00.68%) ++ js-zone(0x1896ef000)
```

Comment: Might be just a buggy extension/addon. Try it with all extensions disabled (menu -> help -> restart with addons disabled)

Comment: Hi Michal thank you but in the memory dump there are different sections for extensions, and those are very small. I did notice that the Developer console does make the problem worse